# How can I find a story or defect I created in VersionOne?

Tags: versionone

We are using Version One. House policy is not to make yourself an owner of a story when you create a defect or story. Sometimes I want to quickly locate a story I recently added, but I can find no way other looking through the entire list of 'Described' stories for that product. Is there a way to filter by the story (or defect) creator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are asking here on Stack Overflow, I assume you mean as an API query.

The first thing you would need to know is the attributes for the VersionOne `Story` asset. If you [explore the attributes](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Recipes/Explore_the_attributes_for_an_asset_type) for `Story` with the [meta.v1](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Documentation/API/Endpoints/meta.v1) endpoint, you will find:

`CreateDate : Date
CreatedBy : Relation to Member`

With that, you can use the [query.v1](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Documentation/API/Endpoints/query.v1) endpoint to query for `Story` with a specific `CreatedBy`, sorted descending on `CreateDate`, with a page size of 100.

`from: Story
select:
  - Number
  - Name
where:
  CreatedBy.Name: Ian Buchanan
sort:
  -CreateDate
page:
  start: 0
  size: 100`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative method to doing a query using our [**rest-1.v1/Data**](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Documentation/API/Endpoints/rest-1.v1%2F%2FData) endpoint.

`https://YourVersionOneInstance/rest-1.v1/Data/Defect?sel=Number,Name,CreateDate&where=CreatedBy.Name='Administrator'&Sort=-CreateDate`

This is not as clean looking as the query.v1 endpoint but it can be dumped right into a browser.

**I will quickly decompose this query just in case some newbs can get a quicky.**

*1) **YourVersionOneInstance/rest-1.v1/Data/Defect**  - I am using the rest-1.v1, Data endpoint to dump out Defects.*

*2)**sel=Number,Name,CreateDate** - I want to show only these attributes (fields) in my output.*

*3) **where=CreatedBy.Name='Administrator'** - I only want output created by Administrator.*

*4) **Sort=-CreateDate`**  - When doing a query without sort, it will show in ascending order  The -CreateDate combination just changes the direction to descending so your latest bubbles to the top.*